# Gettext on Windows 7 doesn't translate

Tags: php, windows, gettext

I have problem with translating my application with gettext.

My code is:

```
<?php
$language = 'cs_CZ';
$translatefile = 'default';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
putenv("LANG=".$language);
bindtextdomain($translatefile, __DIR__.'/locale');
textdomain($translatefile);

echo gettext("ADMIN_LOGIN_PROFESSIONAL");
```

When I run the script it still shows 'ADMIN_LOGIN_PROFESSIONAL'.

My file structure:

- root/

  - index.php
  - locale/

    - cs_CZ/

      - LC_MESSAGES/

        - default.mo

I'm running Windows 7, Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.13.

Thank you very much for any help ...

Comment: is there any relation between the os and server,php ?

Comment: On my colleague's Linux it's working so I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$language = 'cs_CZ';
$translatefile = 'default';
putenv("LC_ALL=".$language);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

bindtextdomain($translatefile, '/locale');
textdomain($translatefile);

echo gettext("ADMIN_LOGIN_PROFESSIONAL");
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, still doesn't work although it's the same code and there is a correct translation in .mo file

Comment: I am testing it right now and it seems there is some change from php 5.2 to 5.3...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on win 7, php 5.3 & 5.4, iis. Is not tested on linux. Code is ready to format dates by `strftime('%c')` etc.:

```
/**
 * Setup locale (strings and formats)
 * @param string $lang Lang code in ISO format ('cs')
 * @see locales:   http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/I18N/locales-list.shtml
 * @see languages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx
 * @see regions:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28vs.71%29.aspx
 */
function setAppLocale($lang)
{
    $domain = 'Tis';

    switch ($lang)
    {
        case 'cs':
            $locale = 'czech';
            $strings = 'cs_CZ';
            break;

        case 'en':
            $locale = 'english';
            $strings = 'en_US';
            break;

        case 'de':
            $locale = 'german';
            $strings = 'de_DE';
            break;

        case 'hu':
            $locale = 'hungarian';
            $strings = 'hu_HU';
            break;

        case 'ru':
            $locale = 'russian';
            $strings = 'ru_RU';
            break;
    }

    putenv("LANGUAGE=$strings");
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

    bindtextdomain($domain, APPDIR . "/locale");
    bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8");
    textdomain($domain);
}
```